# Trying to access array offset on value of type null line 49

Tags: php

Here is the page where I am getting the error. Can someone help me ? I do not understand why I am having this issue

```php
@foreach($allData as $key => $item)
    <tr>
        <td> {{ $key+1}} </td>
        <td>{{ $item['category']['name'] }}</td>
        <td> #{{ $item['invoice']['invoice_no'] }}   </td>
        <td> {{  date('d-m-Y',strtotime($item['invoice']['date'])) }} </td>
        <td> {{ $item->due_amount }} </td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ route('customer.edit.invoice',$item->invoice_id) }}" class="btn btn-info sm" title="Edit Data">  <i class="fas fa-edit"></i> </a>
            <a href="{{ route('customer.invoice.details.pdf',$item->invoice_id) }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger sm" title="Customer Invoice Details">  <i class="fa fa-eye"></i> </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I am trying to print the customer invoice with the category of the product he bought, the name of the product, the invoice number and the date.

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: Is `$item` an array or an object? You have both `$item['category']` (array) and `$item->invoice_id` (object).

Comment: I have used some places $item as object but here, I wouldl like to set it up as an array. The error is happening on the line  <td>{{ $item['category']['name'] }}</td>

Comment: The error indicates that `$item['category']` is null. Can you show an example of `var_dump($allData)`?

Comment: @Barmar how do I display it ?

Comment: Just put that before the loop.

Comment: Here is how I added it. Apologies again for any error, I am learning php xD 

 <tbody>
                        var_dump($allData)

                         @foreach($allData as $key => $item)

Comment: You're missing the `;` after `var_dump($allData)`. It's a separate statement.

Comment: I added it, but when I refresh and run it, it s not displaying properly. Or maybe its me, but here is what I am getting 

SELECT
  *
FROM
  `users`
WHERE
  `id` = ?
limit
  1


7:39:11 PM
0.17MS
MYSQL
SELECT * FROM `payments` WHERE `paid_status` != ?


7:39:11 PM
0.34MS
MYSQL
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE `customers`.`id` = ? limit 1

Comment: I don't know what that is. I assumed `$allData` is an array containing the results of a query, but that seems to be the query itself. How do you set `$allData`?

Comment: This looks like a Blade template, correct? In which case you need to surround PHP code with php tags: `<?php var_dump($allData); ?>` The output you've written in the comment above are SQL queries, that cannot be `$allData` or you'd be seeing different errors, it must be output from some other debugging you are doing - it has timestamps so maybe logfiles?

Comment: I am all new to php. I have started learning that like 2 months ago. and I was working on a project to get more into details. @Don'tPanic I will put the php code in the one where I am having the issue or do i create a new blade.php file with that code

Comment: Here is the error I am getting in the debugging 
 PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $allData in